# Adding button click event when Fancybox popup opened

Tags: jquery, html, click

I'm trying to add a button onclick event to a button tag when I load my Fancybox popup using the following code:

```
var processOrder = function(id) {
    $('#processPopupLink').fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': false,
        'frameWidth': 850,
        'frameHeight': 695
    }).click();

    $('#processComplete').click(function() {
        alert('debug');
    });
}
```

However, it's not showing the message box when I click the button, I have no idea why it is not working, any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I'm not wanting it to click the button, I'm wishing for it to add an onclick to an existing button on the fancybox popup, when the fancybox popup is opened.

Comment: Does `#processComplete` exist? What about moving the assignment of the click handler before the fancybox thing?

Comment: Am I being blind or does the #processComplete ever actually get clicked by that code...?

Comment: Updated my answer in response to your edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Fancybox API](http://fancybox.net/api):

> onComplete - Will be called once the
>   content is displayed.

```
$('#processPopupLink').fancybox({
    onComplete: function() { 
        $('#processComplete').click(function() 
            {
               alert('debug');
            }); 
    }
});
```

Comment: In the new fancybox it's afterShow instead of onComplete