# Fancybox callback - click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I want to add a pagination inside the fancybox. But with the clickevent which is described here: [Adding button click event when Fancybox popup opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920048/adding-button-click-event-when-fancybox-popup-opened) nothing is working.

here is my js code:

```
onComplete: function(){ 

      $(".fancybox-nav").click(function(){  

          console.log("it works");

          var $that = $(this);
          var nav = $that.attr('class');
          var number = $('.fancybox-inner').find('.currentpage').text()
          var intnumber = parseInt(number);
          if (intnumber >= 1 && intnumber <= $('.item').length && nav == 'fancybox-nav fancybox-next') {       
                                    intnumber += 1;
                            }
                            else if(intnumber > 1){
                                intnumber -= 1;
                            };   
                            var stringnumber = String(intnumber);
                            $('.fancybox-inner')
                                .find('.currentpage')
                                    .replaceWith('<span class="currentpage">' + stringnumber + '</span>');    
                        });

                    },
```

How can I implement a click function inside my fancybox?

Comment: Does the console show anything when you change your code to `onComplete: function(){ console.log("it works")},`?

Comment: Also, are you using Fancybox 1 or 2?

Comment: I'm using fancybox2 - the console doesn't show anything - it's not going inside the click-function

Comment: by using just this: onComplete: function(){ console.log("it works")}, the console shows "it works" correctly - it has just the problem with the 2nd function

Comment: with onUpdate the console shows "it works" within the click function - but here the pagination stops by the first +1 - any hints?

Comment: Would be difficult to debug this without a working copy to play with.  I would suggest placing a `debugger;` statement inside the click function and watching what happens as the function executes; verify at each step that the variables have values that look right.

Comment: When you say "_add a pagination inside fancybox_" do you mean something like: http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/numbersInsteadofThumbs_27feb12.html ?.... if so, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9475027/1055987

Comment: Yes I mean this - but I have the version 2.0.6 and can't find any line of the code I have to change...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the pagination effect you are looking for, you may use the fancybox thumbs helper.

[Follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9475027/1055987) to find the instructions of how to customize the `jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js` file for that purpose.

It was written originally for `v2.0.5` but I added some notes at the end of the post for `v2.0.6`.